# Is it possible to put a modern laptop into USB-device mode?

Tags: usb, laptop, drivers

*The goal is to connect this laptop to another via USB-C cable and make it act like a keyboard. The laptop is running Windows/Linux and is charged via USB port (not sure if it's Power Delivery).*

There are surely similar questions already, however, I hope that things changed in recent years with USB-C. Still I understand that [Windows Desktop doesn't support device mode by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-dual-role-driver-stack-architecture).

So far I've discovered that Apple MacBooks can be put into Target Disk mode. They can interchange between USB-host and USB-device, right?
Secondly, I tried Wireshark to capture USB traffic. I've found that when a MacBook is attached, it generates enumeration traffic just like any other device. However when I attach the laptop, there's silence.
Thirdly, I tried digging into Intel's datasheets. It seems to me now that USB management is done inside CPU, because xHCI-support must be a CPU's feature. But Apple used that same Intel processors, why do we get different behaviour?

So the questions are:

1. Do laptops have dedicated USB controllers? If so, are they connected to PCI like other internals? Can they be replaced?
2. How to find if the current hardware is able to act like a device? Is there a list of "correct" controllers?
3. Can I change the mode by only programming and not soldering?

Comment: One question per post. This, and the reasons for it, are laid out in the Help section.

Answer (score 0):

There are existing products that can do this, no need to do it yourself.

Here are two such products :

[**Microsoft Garage Mouse without Borders**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460)

> Mouse without Borders (http://aka.ms/mm) is a product that makes you the captain of your computer fleet by allowing you to control up to four computers from a single mouse and keyboard. This means that with Mouse without Borders you can copy text or drag and drop files across computers.

[**Synergy**](https://symless.com/synergy) (29$)

> Use the keyboard, mouse, or trackpad of one computer to control nearby computers, and work seamlessly between them.

Comment: Nice apps, never heard of them. However they work across LAN and require configuration on both sides, which is not my case. Please consider the goal as a research on "how to let a PC pretend to be a keyboard".

Comment: No product I know of has ever done this, and I have very strong doubts about its existence. These products emulate a keyboard by being present on both sides, and this works because LAN communication is a known and supported protocol. I think you should change your logic.